# Simple Python Docker Script

Tags: python, docker

I have a very simple python script. I am trying to get it to run from within docker. I have simplified it so it just prints `hello world` now.

My docker set up:

[docker-compose.yaml]

```
version: '2'
services:
   dev:
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./app.py:/app.py
```

[Dockerfile]

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev build-essential libpq-dev


ADD ./requirements /code/requirements

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r /code/requirements/base.txt

VOLUME /app.py

CMD ["python","/app.py"]
```

When I run docker-compose up I get the following error:

> ERROR: for dev  Cannot start service dev: oci runtime error: exec:
>   "Python": executable file not found in $PATH

However, docker should be built into the Ubuntu Image. It is the same image I use for my Python Flask script but that works no issue.

Comment: Is python already installed in the base ubunu image? I dont thin so. To use this image you should minimal do an apt-get update and then apt-get install your stuff in the docker file before calling any none existing command

Comment: Apologies, I have added in the two lines into the dockerfile which I had removed when trying different base images.

Comment: In the second line you copy a file or directory with the name "requirements" into the container. But your not installing or registering anthing in ubuntus environment

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: You completely changed your question during my last comment. Useless to talk further. Use this: https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a genuine mistake leaving out two lines which I added. In my naivety I don't see how it completely changes the question.

Comment: You need use python slim imagen from https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the python you have installed can't be found by ubuntu. I suggest adding to your dockerfile (after the line that installs python):

```
RUN "PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7" >> ~/.bashrc
CMD source ~/.bashrc && <other commands>
```

Or

```
RUN "PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.4" >> ~/.bashrc
CMD source ~/.bashrc && <other commands>
```

If you would rather use Python3

That will add your python path to your bash register file and have it take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but with a different settings, with apt-get I installed python3 and I used the command python, so it was not seeing the path to the python3 bin because it was looking for python.

What I suggest is to try the same thing I did with python3 installing it and all the packages you need

---

`FROM ubuntu:16.04`

`RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y  python3-pip python3-dev build-essential`

`COPY . /usr/src/app`
`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`

`CMD ["python3", "file.py"]`

---

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to print a 'Hello world' (or anything that does not need an additional library), you can use the following template:

[docker-compose.yml]

```
version: '2'
services:
    my_service:
        build: ./<service_dir_name> # replace <.> with the directory containing your files in the current directory where .yml is located.
```

[Dockerfile]

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

# Copy your files in this order: <files in the current dir>  <destination in the container>
COPY codes/ /app

WORKDIR app
ENTRYPOINT python -u my_code.py
```

alpine is a very light linux with python pre-installed. In case you need to add some libraries, add

```
RUN pip install <library>
```

to the Dockerfile. Your python code is located in the

```
<files in the current dir>
```

Hope that helps.